# Alquiler de equipos

Tags: php, mysql

Hoy necesito hacer una página donde se puedan alquilar instrumentos de música. Tengo una página *php* donde muestro los instrumentos disponibles. Encima del mismo tengo un cajón donde la persona que quiera alquilar pone el modelo que quiere. Simplemente tendría que poner el nombre del modelo, darle a alquilar y el objeto quedaría alquilado, pasando de la tabla en  *mysql* de `equipos_alquilar` a `equipos_alquilados`, restándose uno en la tabla `equipos_alquilar` y añadiéndola/creándola en `equipos_alquilados`.

Lo he intentado hacer pero me salen dos errores que no se como solucionar.
Los errores son:

> **Warning:** mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\musicalia\alquilar.php on line 19
>
> **Warning:** mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\musicalia\alquilar.php on
>   line 20

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar estaría enormemente agradecida, ya que llevo varios días desesperada con esto.

El código de las dos páginas que estoy utilizando son:

**equipos_aluguer.php**

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','equipamentos');
session_start();
?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dando estilo a tablas</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="diseño/tablas.css">
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="main-container" action="alquilar.php" method="post" >

        <table action="alquilar.php" method="post">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Equipos disponibles</th><th>cantidade</th><th>descripcion</th><th>marca</th><th>prezo</th><th>foto</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
    <?php
    $sql="SELECT * from equipo_aluguer";
      $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
      while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $_session['producto']=$mostrar;
       ?>
        <tr>
                <td><?php echo $mostrar['modelo'] ?></td>

                <td><?php echo $mostrar['cantidade'] ?></td>

                <td><?php echo $mostrar['descripcion'] ?></td>

        <td><?php echo $mostrar['marca'] ?></td>

        <td><?php echo $mostrar['prezo'] ?></td>

        <td><?php echo $mostrar['foto'] ?></td>
            </tr>
      <form action="alquilar.php" method="POST">
      <input name="modelo" type="text" placeholder="Mete lo que quieras alquilar">
      <input type="submit" value="Alquilar">
        <?php
}
    ?>
        </table>
    </div>
  <button onclick="location.href='menu.php'">Volver ao menu</button>

 </body>
 </html>
```

**alquilar.php**

```
<?php

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "equipamentos";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if (!$conn)
{
    die("No hay conexión: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
session_start();
$modelo = $_POST["modelo"];

$_SESSION["modelo"]= $modelo;

$q = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM equipo_aluguer WHERE modelo = '$modelo'");
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$q);
  while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $mostrar['modelo'];
        $mostrar['cantidade'];
        $mostrar['descripcion'];
        $mostrar['marca'];
        $mostrar['prezo'];
        $mostrar['foto'];
if($mostrar['cantidade'] > 1 )
{
$a=$mostrar-1;
if ("SELECT '$modelo' from equipo_alugado"){
mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE '$mostrar' INTO equipo_alugado");}
else{
mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO equipo_alugado VALUES '$mostrar'");
}
}
else if ($modelo==null){
header('Refresh:1; url=equiposaluguer.php'); echo 'campos vacios';
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

El error lo tienes en el archivo `alquilar.php`, justamente en esta linea

```php
$q = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM equipo_aluguer WHERE modelo = '$modelo'");
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$q);
```

que deberia ser algo asi:

```php
$q ="SELECT * FROM equipo_aluguer WHERE modelo = '$modelo'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$q);
```

Como el error te lo indica le estabas pasando un `objeto` en vez de un `string`

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente deberías hacer un hecho del query que estas enviando y posteriormente meterlo directamente en como consulta en la base de datos.

El problema que veo principalmente y fijándome en el mensaje de error es que estas pasando un argumento como un integer y espera un string.

Deberías convertirlo a string el "$modelo"

prueba con  `$modelo = strval ($_POST["modelo"]);`